# How to pass variable from (main activity to another) activity to custom view in Android C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm new to programming and I'm having a problem passing a variable from an activity to my custom view.

In my main activity I put a string to a new activity (Analysis) using:

```
Intent a = new Intent (this, typeof(Analysis));
a.PutExtra("speedvalues", mapclass.Speed());
StartActivity (a);
```

In the Analysis activity I use the following method to retrieve it:

```
string s = Intent.GetStringExtra("speedvalues");
```

This all works fine. However, I need to pass this string to another class (my custom view class) that I call whenever my new activity is opened. Because I need this string to draw a graph/line using my custom view class.

Can someone please tell me how I can do this? I tried declaring string s as a static string, but that resulted in an exception error.

Edit:

Here is a part of my custom View class as requested:

```
class Graph : View
{
    List<int> speedvalues = new List<int>(StringToListInt(VARIABLE FROM ACTIVITY));
    List<PointF> graphpoints = new List<PointF>();
    int padding = 100;

    public Graph(Context c) : base(c)
    {
    this.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
    }

    public float MaxSpeed()
    { [...] }

    public static List<int> StringToListInt(string x)
    { [...] }                   

    public void GraphPoints()
    { [...] }                   

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas cv)
    { [...] }
```

Edit 2:

Thanks for the answers guys! I checked the most helpful one.

I found a solution myself too. I created a new static string and a static method. I assigned the new static string to the value of "speedvalues" using the static method:

```
public class Analysis : Activity

    Graph graph;
    public static string s5;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        [...]

        string s4 = Intent.GetStringExtra("speedvalues");
        s5 = StringToG (s4);
        graph = new Graph(this);
    }

    private static string StringToG(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }
```

And of course in the Graph class I retrieve the value using:

```
string speedvalues = Analysis.s5;
```

So far this one works. Is this version better or worse?

Comment: post your custom class

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply. I added a part of the custom View class.

Comment: Good to know that you found the solution. But using static is not a good practice. Statics are EVIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the values and ondraw is called already. 
So inorder to prevent ondraw please find the below modified your code.

```
class Graph : View
{
    List<int> speedvalues;
    List<PointF> graphpoints = new List<PointF>();
    int padding = 100;
    bool isReady = false;

    public Graph(Context c) : base(c)
    {
    this.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
    }

    public float MaxSpeed()
    { [...] }

    public static List<int> StringToListInt(string x)
    { [...] }                   

    public void GraphPoints()
    { [...] }                   

    public void ReadyToDraw(bool ready)
    {
        isReady=ready;
    }

    public static List<int> StringToListInt(string x)
    { 
        speedvalues=new List<int>(StringToListInt(x));
    } 

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas cv)
    { 
     base.OnDraw(canvas);
    if(ReadyToDraw)
    {
    //Your drawing code
    }
    }
}
```

Then pass values like below

```
string s = Intent.GetStringExtra("speedvalues");

Graph g=new Graph(this);
g.StringToListInt(s);//Assign values
g.ReadyToDraw(true);//Set it is ready to draw
g.invalidate(); // Draw
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a really good solution. I found a solution myself too by using a new static string and a static method. I added my solution in the question section.

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answers, you have another option called **Shared Preferences**.

You can Store Variable in main activity and get it in any class.

There are many Tutorials found through google like this one for example

http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126&aaid=146

Comment: Thank you! This is very handy for in the future.

Comment: In this case shared preferences are not preferable.

Answer (score -1):

## 1. Change

```
List<int> speedvalues = new List<int>(StringToListInt(VARIABLE FROM ACTIVITY));
```

## 2. to

```
List<int> speedvalues  ;
```

---

## 3. Change

```
public Graph(Context c) : base(c)
{
    this.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
}
```

## 4. to

```
public Graph(Context c , string speedvalues ) : base(c)
{
    this.peedvalues = new List<int>(StringToListInt(speedvalues));
    this.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
}
```

---

## 5. Change

```
 string s4 = Intent.GetStringExtra("speedvalues");
 s5 = StringToG (s4);
 graph = new Graph(this);
```

## 6. to

```
 string s4 = Intent.GetStringExtra("speedvalues");
 graph = new Graph(this , StringToG(s4));
```

---

### full code

```
class Graph : View
{
    List<int> speedvalues  ;

    public Graph(Context c , string speedvalues ) : base(c)
    {

       this.peedvalues = new List<int>(StringToListInt(speedvalues));

       this.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);

    }
}
```

[base (C# Reference) msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, my question was how I can get the string "speedvalues" from the Activity class to the View class.

Comment: Welcome, you can do it this way also , i updated the answer to show you how to pass it check step no 6